# Better way to add number to itself?

Tags: php, variables

Is there a better/shorter way in PHP of doing

```
$x = $x + 10;
```

i.e.

something like

```
$x .= 10; // (but this doesn't add together)
```

I am sure i've seen a shorter way than doing `$x = $x + 10;`

Comment: FYI, `.=` is for string concatenation.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Have a look at: http://php.net/manual/language.operators.assignment.php (in the code examples and comments)

You can use:

```
$x += 10;
```

for example.

Comment: does $x need to defined beforehand?

Answer (score 19):

Not a PHP guy, but `$x += 10;` maybe?

Answer (score 15):

`$x += 10;`

However some people find this harder to read.

What you tried (`$x.= 10`) works only for strings.

E.g.

```
$x = 'test';
$x.= 'ing...';
```

Answer (score 8):

Like in many other languages:

```
$x += 10;
```

More information: [*Assignment Operators*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)

Comment: do not count Delphi to those languages :)

Answer (score 4):

```
$x+=10;
```

Is this what you're wanting?

Answer (score 4):

`$x += 10;` adds 10 to `$x`

**or**

`$x += $x;` adds `$x` to itself, but you could just do: `$x *= 2;`

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for this:

```
$x += 10;
```

Answer (score 3):

$x +=10; is equivalent to $x = $x +10;

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/operators.php

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty simple. $x += 10; is same as $x = $x + 10;