# How to add up numbers in PHP to create a unique score and save it

Tags: php, html, numbers, addition, points

I am making a 'health program' and you get 1 point per 'healthy' thing you do each day, for example, if you have 30 minutes of exercise you get a point. How it works is shown below:

```html
<form method="post">
    <label>Did you have 30 minutes of exercise today? (+1)</label>
    <select name="question">
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
  </select> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light"  name="form1">
</form>
<form method="post">
    <label>Have you drinken 8 glasses of water today? (+1)</label>
    <select name="question">
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
  </select> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light"  name="form2">
</form>
<form method="post">
    <label>Did you use your phone for more than two hours today? (-1)</label>
    <select name="question">
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
  </select> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light"  name="form3">
</form>



<?php
/* Then using PHP I want to have each form submitted, add or remove 1 from an overall score, something like this: */
$score = 0;
if (isset($_POST['form1'])) {
  $question = $_POST['question'];
  if ($question = "yes") {
    // +1 point
    $score = +1;
  }
}

if (isset($_POST['form2'])) {
  $question = $_POST['question'];
  if ($question = "yes") {
    // +1 point
    $score = +1;
  }
}
if (isset($_POST['form3'])) {
  if ($question = "yes") {
     // -1 point
     $score = +1;
  }
} ?>
```

Then I want either +1 or -1 from $score. I'm not sure how to do the actual adding of the points using PHP. I want the $score to be updated outside of the if statement otherwise, for each if statement it will add one and $score will still be = to 1

Thanks!

Jacob

Comment: Can you give us more detail about exactly what you want to have happen - for example, when you click on a Submit button, what should happen?

Comment: I want to have the $score have 1 added to it or removed from it every time making an accumulating number, to compare to other users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better way to add number to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495848/better-way-to-add-number-to-itself)

Comment: And by the way, the variables won't store the value for ever, once the script finishes executing the value is gone, you need to use a database.

Comment: You need something to store the variables each time the script executes. Else, you will simply lose the variables after page reload.

Comment: How would I go about creating a database to store the values?

Comment: You can use $_SESSION to store your values. like `$_SESSION['score'] = 0;`. To add use `$_SESSION['score'] += 1;` for substract use `$_SESSION['score'] -= 1;`

Comment: Why do you have separate forms for each question? Will the user be able to answer only one of those? And let's say you correctly score the user, what would happen then? How are you planning to compare to other users?

Comment: I have different forms for each question so once they answer the question I can make it disappear until the next day using a cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store the data and can do it in different places. Here's some of them:

- session
- cookies
- server cache
- browser local storage
- database
- ...

Within a normal website scope, you'd usually go with a database.
Each time you submit the form and process the data in the backend of your application (remember that php cannot be execute on the client), you save the data and use it for subsequent data processing.

It seems to me that javascript would better handle what you're trying to achieve, allowing you to update the interface realtime, bypassing completely the need to send the form to the backend. In this case you can choose to send the total form score to the backend or save it directly to storage accessible from javascript (cookies, local storage, ...).
Again, the most common way to do this is as follows:

1. process data with javascript and update interface
2. send processed data to backend along with unprocessed data to validate user input (one may "fake" javascript data)
3. in the server, save data to backend
4. when rendering the html page, use php with backend values to only show relevant content
5. repeat

If it is a must to use php (maybe you are working on an assignment) and cannot use a database, you may want to combine all the answers in one single form:

```
<form method="post">
  <div>
    <label>Did you have 30 minutes of exercise today? (+1)</label>
    <select name="question0">
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
  </div>
  <div>
  </select> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light"  name="form1">
    <label>Have you drinken 8 glasses of water today? (+1)</label>
    <select name="question1">
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
  </div>
  <div>
  </select> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light"  name="form2">
    <label>Did you use your phone for more than two hours today? (-1)</label>
    <select name="question2">
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
  </select> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light"  name="form3">
</div>
</form>


// BackendController.php
<?php
$score = 0; // or grab initial value from persistent storage (cookie, db, etc)
$questions = ['question0', 'question1', 'question2'];
foreach($questions as $question) {
  $val = $_POST[$question];
  $question == 'yes' ? $score++ : $score--;  
}

?>
```

This way you can send and process all parameters in a single shot, and can also shorten the php script. Still, remember that you will lose the data once the connection is closed. In this case, you may want to save the result to session or cookie and use that retrieved value each next request.